# Solve a problem using Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

We have the following problem:

> At the beginning of every year, a gardener classifies his soil based on its quality: it's either **good**, **mediocre** or **bad**. Assume that the classification of the soil has a stochastic nature which only depends on last year's classification and never improves. We have the following information:
>
> - If the soil is **good**, then the classification next year will be good ($p=0.2$), mediocre ($p=0.5$) or bad ($p=0.3$).
> - If the soil is **mediocre**, then the classification next year will be mediocre ($p=0.5$) or bad ($p=0.5$).
> - If the soil is **bad**, then the classification next year will be bad ($p=1$).
>
> The gardener can also pay to have the soil fertilized, which will change the probabilities as follows:
>
> - If the soil is **good**, then the classification next year will be good ($p=0.3$), mediocre ($p=0.6$) or bad ($p=0.1$).
> - If the soil is **mediocre**, then the classification next year will be good ($p=0.2$), mediocre ($p=0.6$) or bad ($p=0.2$).
> - If the soil is **bad**, then the classification next year will be good ($p=0.1$), mediocre ($p=0.4$) or bad ($p=0.5$).
>
> The costs for fertilization are $\$1000$ for good soil, $\$2000$ for mediocre soil and $\$10,000$ for bad soil.
>
> The gardener can sell his soil: good soil sells for $\$10000$, mediocre soil sells for $\$6000$ and bad soil sells for $\$2000$.
>
> When should the gardener fertilize, and when shouldn't he?

I want to tackle this problem using Markov chains but I'm having trouble. I know the state space is given by $S = \{ \mbox{good, mediocre, bad}  \}$, but I'm having trouble formulating the Markov chains. Would appreciate help.

Comment: In the second part, you wrote "if the soil is good" three times. I assume you want to change that.

Comment: You don't need a Markov chain. If the soil is good, he'll sell since it won't get any better. If the soil is bad, he'll sell since cost of fertilizing bad soll is more than gain from moving up to good soil. In the mediocre state selling (6K) dominates not fertilizing. If he fertilizes (2K) he'll only gain 4K with probability 0.2, so he shouldn't fertilize and should sell. So he should stop being a farmer and sell, sell, sell.

Comment: @A.S. Hadn't thought about that. The question must be incorrect then, seems kind of pointless. I thought it would be a good question to solve using Markov chains, guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soil condition at start of the year is known, and fertilization will only change the soil **next year**, so in taking a decision, we should look at its effect on next year's profits.

If soil is "good", next year's profits (thousands of dollars) will be:

$0.2*10 + 0.5*6 + 0.3*2 =5.6$ without fertilization,

and $0.3*10 + 0.6*6 + 0.1*2 - 1 = 5.8 $ with fertilization,

so **fertilize**

Work out similarly for the other 2 states.

---

Note that you will have to take such decisions every year.

Comment: Why would the farmer waste money fertilizing instead of selling right away?

Comment: @A.S.: I take it that the produce was sold and the land is fallow at start, else there is no point in the question !

Comment: I see. My literal interpretation of the question is inferior, though it should pass for a valid answer in OP's homework ;).

Comment: What about fertilizing bad soil twice in a row for example?

Comment: Do you mean twice in the same year ? No such data is given, so we can't say anything. From the practical point of view, you *could* use fertilizers after every crop, if you are sowing, say, twice a year. But why complicate an already murky problem ?

Comment: hey @trueblueanil, I think the math is wrong for the second example (with fertilization), it should be 6.7 not 5.8